# How to enforce jenkins job to wait until all jobs executed in loop

Tags: jenkins, groovy, parallel-processing, jenkins-pipeline

In this i have requirement to trigger my job with 3 iterations (below example 3) without waiting, but after all 3 jobs were triggered this has to wait until all 3 jobs have successfully finished irrespective of fail or pass.

I am using wait:`true` but that will wait for each iteration, thats not i want.
If I use wait:`false` , it's not waiting once all iterations in loop has completed, its not waiting for the downstream jobs to finish. I want the current job to wait until i got result of jobs (3 pipelines).

```groovy
//job1 is a pipeline job which i am triggering multiple times with different params

stage {
    for(int cntr=0;i<3;i++) {
         build job : "job1",
         parameters: [string(name: 'param1', value:val[cntr] )],
         wait: false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what you actually want is to run them all in parallel and then wait until they all finish.
To do so you can use the [parallel](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-cps/#parallel-execute-in-parallel) keyword:

> `parallel`: Execute in parallel.
> Takes a map from branch names to closures and an optional argument failFast >which will terminate all branches upon a failure in any other branch:
>
> ````
> parallel firstBranch: {
>     // do something
> }, secondBranch: {
>     // do something else
> },
> failFast: true|false```
> ````

In your case it can look something like:

```
 stage('Build Jobs') {
     def values = ['value1', 'value2', 'value2']
     parallel values.collectEntries {value ->
         ["Building With ${value}": {
             build job : "job1",
                   parameters: [string(name: 'param1', value: value)],
                   wait: true
         }]
     }
 }
```

Or if you want to use indexes instead of a constant list:

```
    stage('Build Jobs') {
        def range = 0..2 //  or range = [0, 1, 2]
        parallel range.collectEntries { num ->
            ["Iteration ${num}": {
                build job : "job1",
                      parameters: [string(name: 'param1', value: somefunc(num)],
                      wait: true
            }]
        }
    }
```

This will execute all the jobs in parallel and then wait until they are all finished before progressing with the pipeline (don't forget to set the `wait` parameter of the `build` step to `true`).
You can find more examples for things like this [here](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/examples/).

Comment: Thanks Noam. I need one more in this ..I have 5 parameters and values.  First i will loop through and create a list of values (3 times). Now how do you want me to iterate a Map which has a key and value as list; can you please help me with example

Comment: What exactly do you mean? you have 5 different parameters that needs to be passed to the job and each parameter has a different value? i am not quite sure i understand your parameter layout, can you give an example?

Comment: for (int cntr=0;cntr<3;cntr ++ )
   {

       build job :"jobname",
       parameters: 
       [
        string(name: 'a', value: samplefunction[cntr]),
        string(name: 'b', value: difffunction[cntr]),
        string(name: 'c', value: someotherfunction[cntr])
       ]
   }


Here i am getting each parameter value from a function which will provide the output by taking a iterator .. for each iterator i will get a different value. Please let me know how it can fit into this.

Comment: @reachit i update the answer with an example that uses a range and indexes. it should help you achieve what you need.

Comment: jobs got triggered with params but getting an exception like below. Whats wrong?
an exception which occurred:
 in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.BlockScopeEnv.locals
in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup@6a42ff6d
Caused: java.io.NotSerializableException: groovy.lang.IntRange
 at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1363)
 at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor57.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

Comment: @noma seems i am also facing this issue https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-63074 , could you please let me know how to fix this>

Comment: Just use `def range = [0, 1, 2]` instead of `def range = 0..2`

Comment: Perfect @noam. Worked very well. Thanks for your help !! Appreciate.