# How can you run parallel jobs on a scripted Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I've got a parent pipeline that triggers another one. I'm using `build job:` here. When the pipeline runs, the pipeline triggers the the child job but the child jobs run 1 by 1, waiting for each one to finish.

How can I make all 4 services deployment happen simultaneously?

```
def SERVICES = [""]
if (SERVICE_GROUP == '') {
    SERVICES = ["some-ms1", "some-ms2", "some-ms3", "some-ms4"]
}
.....

        stage("Services Deploy Development") {
          node ("jenkins-slave-dev") {
            if (env.ENV == 'development'){
              for (SERVICE in SERVICES) {
                def job_exec_details = build job: "${SERVICE_GROUP}-${SERVICE}/${DEPLOY_BRANCH}", parameters: [string(name: 'DOCKER_BUILD', value: 'false'),string(name: 'DEPLOY_DEVELOPMENT', value: 'true'),string(name: 'TAG_OVERRIDE', value: "${VERSION_TAG}")], propagate: false, wait: true
              }
            }
            else {
              Utils.markStageSkippedForConditional("Services Deploy Development")
            }
          }
        }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to enforce jenkins job to wait until all jobs executed in loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68824320/how-to-enforce-jenkins-job-to-wait-until-all-jobs-executed-in-loop)

Comment: I think it does, thank you